# How can I create a website popup display to show what websites look like when rendered on a mobile device?

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I'm building a website to showcase the websites that I have created. On my postfolio page I would like have an iphone icon that when clicked, a pop-up shows what the website looks like on an ios device. Ideally, I would like it to look like the iphone simulator that comes with x-code. In other words, instead of having pop-up showing what the website looks like as a still image, I would like the user to be able to scroll up and down and explore the actual website with out leaving my website. I would imagine I'm going to have explore some ajax to make this happen. But I would like to get a clearer picture of what it's going to take to make this happen.

I would like to achieve something like this except with a live view of the webpage with a predetermined width and height. Click on the images in this link: http://www.sphinxnow.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any online services or methods for faking iOS browser rendering on the web.  If you are only looking to let visitors pan around a bit, would it work to just get screen-shots directly from an iOS device and then post those?

It doesn't look like this site properly sets the browser user-agent, but you could try this site - http://www.testiphone.com/.  Maybe they have api available.

That or this site - http://iphone4simulator.com/, this one looks a little more professional.  If they have an API, you are in luck. Otherwise iframe it?

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.